# Nginx rewriting based on request method and get variables

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to rewrite /wp-login.php?action=register to /register, but only if it's a GET request.

Here's what I have so far, while it doesn't error it just doesn't do anything..

```
location /wp-login.php {
    if ( $request_method = GET ) {
        set $login_post_req "herp";
    }

    if ( $args ~ ^action=(register) ) {
        set $login_post_req "${login_post_req}derp";
    }

    if ( $login_post_req = "herpderp" ) {
        rewrite / /register permanent;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    if ( $login_post_req = "herpderp" ) {
    rewrite /wp-login.php /register permanent;
    break;
```

maybe this:

```
rewrite /wp-login.php /register? permanent;
```

to avoid /register/?action=register

Comment: I'd tried that previously and it doesn't seem to make a difference.Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry ... dont have access to my ngninx box right now, will work on it tonight. On the surface it doesnt seem that hard to make it work!

Comment: Thanks man. I tried moving it inside my main location / block as well like so http://d.pr/pcGy but the fundamental problem seems to be I can't even get a basic rewrite from wp-login.php to /register working. I've tried just rewrite ^(/wp-login.php) /register permanent; on it's own and still no joy :/